# How long does coconut curry last in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, curry, coconut

I have three day old green coconut chicken curry in the fridge and am wondering if coconut milk goes bad very quickly. (This is complicated slightly by the power cut we had two days ago for 12 hours. I ate a bit of leftover pork after the power cut and it was fine and the milk was also fine. My house is not hot as it's fall and we are not using heat, the fridge seemed pretty cold but unfortunately I didn't have a thermometer).

My question is that seeing how some foods were fine, would coconut curry be more of a problem than say cooked meat or milk?

I have spent time in Indonesia where they keep cooked food overnight in a cupboard and don't get sick (generally) vs. the extreme-sounding food safety stuff has me confused. Thanks!

Comment: I'd throw it out given the power cut. Not worth getting food poisoning over.

Comment: Personally I'd taste it and heat it properly, then try it. Unless you have relevant health issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @ElendilTheTall. Coconut milk and such based products do not have a long fresh shelf life. Personally, I would discard and not take the risk.

That said, I don't know where you are located and what standard practices apply. In a lot of cases common sense can apply as to how to handle.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't open the refrigerator during the power cut (or only opened it once or twice very briefly), it would have stayed cool enough that nothing would spoil. But because it wasn't quite as cold as it should be, its contents will have a shorter shelf life.